# Wrong ORDER BY with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, timestamp

In my MySQL there's a column named date, type is `timestamp`.

Using this in my PHP scrip:

`$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id, date FROM my_table ORDER BY DATE(date) ASC, TIME(date) DESC');`

output is:

```
2016-11-26 16:55:30
2016-11-26 16:53:08
2016-11-26 16:37:25
2016-11-26 16:32:29
2016-11-26 16:18:57
2016-11-28 19:37:37
```

But that's the wrong order. I want to have the newest date on top, including date and time.

Means:

```
2016-11-28 19:37:37
2016-11-26 16:55:30
2016-11-26 16:53:08
2016-11-26 16:37:25
2016-11-26 16:32:29
2016-11-26 16:18:57
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't separate it out by date/time. Just do `ORDER BY \`date\` DESC`

Comment: as others have pointed out you can sort on the entire column.  But to specifically point out your problem it was because you had DATE(date) ASC.  ASC means ascending so you where sorting by ascending date but descending time.  Changing ASC to DESC would have solved your issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just have `order by` on the entire column value rather than sorting the date part and time part separately

```
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT id, date FROM my_table ORDER BY date DESC`